# Routing - Route specific Internal IP''s over VPN device

Tags: linux, centos, openvpn, iptables

I'm running OpenVPN with some configs on a centOS7 machine. They connect to remote VPN sites and sometimes they change ip after a reboot. They are called tun0, tun1 etc.

Now i need some devices to go over the VPN. For example:

> 192.168.1.20/24 need to go to tun0
>
> 192.168.1.25/24 need to go to tun1
>
> 192.168.1.30/24 need to go to tun2

Is there any way to set up an ip route for this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to reach a _remote_ 192.168.1.30 over the tun2 VPN, or do you want a _local_ 192.168.1.30 device to be forced through the tun2 VPN?

Comment: It has to be forced over the TUN.